# Using cookie to get month, date and time. However, they are not printing and I'm getting undefined for date?

Tags: javascript, html, date, cookies, time

I have the code below. I'm getting an undefined or an error in this line `var datemsg = nameOfMonths[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate();.

If I simply use `var date = new Date();` the values are printed on HTML page. But using the code I intend to use below using `getCookie("date")` to get the date from the browser. It gives me an error and it won't print the date and time.

```
<body onload="setsaveCookie(); loadSaveCookies()">
<h1 class="header">Welcome your visit started on <span id="date"></span> at <span id="time"></span> <span id="ampm"></span></h1>
```

```
function setsaveCookie() {
  var date = new Date();
  setCookie("date", date, 30);

  getDate();
}

function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, expires) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var dayexpires = "expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";" + dayexpires + ";path=/";
  var msg = "";
}

function getDate() {
  var date = new Date();
  var nameOfMonths = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
  var ampm = "";
  var date = getCookie("date");
  var twelvehourtime = "";
  var datemsg = nameOfMonths[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate();
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = datemsg;
}

function getCookie(cookieName) {
  var name = cookieName + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);

  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');

  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Comment: At a glance, you have no loadSaveCookies() function? Even after your edit.

Comment: Your parameter names on your `setCookie` function are very confusing, since `cookieValue` is actually the name of the cookie and `length` is the value of the cookie.

Comment: @Snowmonkey I must have forgotten since I have a lengthy code for getDate function, so I tried to cut them into smaller pieces.

Comment: `date` in `getDate` is a string, not a `Date` object. You need to parse the date value.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan Thanks! I got it and is now working :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the revised version for the getDate function.

```
function getDate() {
var nameOfMonths = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    var ampm = "";
    var date = getCookie("date");
    var dt = new Date(date);
    var twelvehourtime = "";
    var datemsg = nameOfMonths[dt.getMonth()] + " " + dt.getDate();
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = datemsg;
}
```